# Finding the smallest box that can contain an implicitly defined function

Tags: math

If I have an implicitly defined mathematical function like x^2+y^2 = 1 - kx^2y^2. How do I find the smallest box that can contain the graph of the function? Finding the domain and range seems like the right thing to do, but I don't think I ever learned how to do this and googling around hasn't really lead me to find out how to do this.

To be honest the question is related to the "love curve" (x^2 + y^2 -1)^3 = x^2y^3 I don't know if it is a different technique than the other one, but I am much more interested in learning how it's solved than just being spoon fed an answer.

Anybody got that math flex out there?

Comment: Can you define "box" more precisely? I assume you're picturing a rectangle; do its sides need to be parallel to the x- and y-axes?

Comment: You are right. I do mean a rectangle. I think it's sides do need to be parallel. Sorry for the ambiguity.